# Best approach (software even) for Rigid registration of two 2D Point Sets with known member correspondences

Tags: linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, rigid-transformation

Let's assume that I have in 2D space, an initial set of N points.
I take these points, I move them a bit and I consider their new positions as a new Set.

Given that I know the point correspondences (i.e. which point went where), is there any algorithm that can reposition them altogether via a Rigid transformation, so that the total position residuals are minimized?

Can this even be calculated deterministically?